# Filtering a view of 20 thousands rows takes 30minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

My issue is i have a view that returns 20.000 lines of data for a certain day

```
select * from view
where date = X
```

but then when i add a where clause for the perimeter i need

```
select * from view 
where date = X and perimeter in ( 'A' , 'B' , 'C', 'D' )
```

the result is 10.000 lines more or less but it takes up to 30minutes to get the result.

The view is quite complicated with dozens of joins and agregates etc

how can i fix that ?

Thanks for your help, 
and i you have any question, ask me :)

** UPDATE : thanks for your answers .
 The real query is pretty complicated. This is only an example to explain my problem. The execution plan is quite long and unuseful since i have the the exact (100%) same execution plan ( estimated and real ) 
whether i use the filter on the perimeter column or not. 
but time behind that goes from 30secondes when i only filter date to  30minutes when i add the perimter filter.
so it must mean that the execution plan is wrong anyways.
statistics are normally updated on that tables.
there is no index on this column on the table where i seek it. is adding one necessary for the view ?
The column we filter on is retrieved thanks to a left join in the view
**

Comment: You would have to show us the query plan, some schema details, indexes that are in place, View SQL etc, we are flying blind to solving the problem right now.

Comment: Providing the definition (DDL) of the `VIEW` and the tables the View is referencing **including** any indexes, and the [Query Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) will greatly help us help you.

Comment: I would suggest dump the complete result of the View into a temporary table, and then performing the filtered select on that table.     Sometimes what appears to be a small change to a query will result in a big change to the execution plan, and despite SQL Server doing its best, this sometimes results in a much slower response.   If executing select * from View where Day=X is fast, then just take those results and dump them into a temporary table, and then query that table with the IN clause.

Answer (score 0):

First ask yourself:

> Is it normal to take such time?

In some case, when data is huge and statements are complex, is normal for certain query to take more time.

If this is not your case, then:

- Do I need all columns? - why `SELECT *`, selecting only the needed columns can optimize the view execution sometimes
- Do I need all the logic used in the view? - if the view is so complex, think if it is possible to get only the statements you need (for example, create separate view with less logic, less data sources, less columns)
- Is the query using the best indexes - this is [huge topic](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairways/stairway-to-sql-server-indexes), but you are performing `filtering`, so it might be possible to optimize the query using appropriate index or even [filtered index?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)
- Can I filtered the data in advance? - sometimes you can create [inline table-valued function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in order to perform filtering in advance (the function is basically a view with parameters - imagine passing parameter 'X' to this function, which will be passed to other function refereed in the view returning now only 5% of the rows generated previously - so, may be some of the values in your `WHERE` clauses can be passed as paramateres);
- Do I need to materialized this view? - it is a last resort, but you can [create index on the view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017) in order to materialized it like ordinary table and optimize performance, further (note, that not every view can be indexed)

From what I have seen, a lot of developers are using legacy views, created for solving particular issues in the past, instead creating new ones. And many many times, these views are doing much more then actually is needed.